# MYSQL like clause finding too many matches

Tags: mysql, where-clause, sql-like

Yesterday, the lady that uses the products sold report came to me with an issue.  The report returns a list of all products we sell with a count for a given time period.  The report had too many results in one product.  The product "sale page" line also counted "unlimited sale page" an upgrade product we sell.

This is the code that gave the wrong results:

```
Select count(WorkOrderId) as cnt from tblworkorder 
where PlanName LIKE '%{$row['PlanType']}%' and RecTime BETWEEN '$stime' and '$etime'
```

The problem has to do with the wild card matches.  However, because of how my predecessor set up the db, it's needed.  A sale can be multiple products, each listed by name in the PlanName column, separated by commas.  Example,

```
PlanName = Sale Page, Domain Name,
PlanName = Link, Unlimited Sale Page,
```

While the correct answer is 1 on each line, the current code would return:

```
Domain Name = 1
Link = 1
Sale Page = 2
Unlimited Sale Page = 1
```

If the product were "Sale Page-Unlimited" I could have the code add a comma to the end of the plan name it is searching for (e.g. "Sale Page,").  Since the problem comes at the front (and I cannot guarantee that Sale Page will always be the first in the list), that won't solve this problem.  But it might prevent a similar issue in the future.

Without restructuring the database to have a column where plans are listed by number (e.g. "P4, P16, P25," or "P1, P11,") or a join table, how can I find only Sale Page and not Unlimited Sale Page on the line when I run the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) which would translate to something like

```
SELECT 
    count(WorkOrderId) as cnt 
FROM tblworkorder 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('{$row['PlanType']}',PlanName)>0 
  AND RecTime BETWEEN '$stime' and '$etime'
```

But the real answer is to normalise your data so you have an order table and an orderPlans table which has foreign key columns linking to order_ids and plan_ids.

Comment: That even sped it up!  And if I am asked to rewrite this project, I **will** be normalizing it all over the place.  But until then, there are too many potential side effects.  I didn't write this app to start with.